# Need Table Sorter (Manually Done)

Tags: php, jquery, html, sorting, html-table

I am having a table as follows in a webpage to show the results fetched from DB,

```
<table id="newspaper-a">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Word</th>
            <th scope="col">Rank</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>stol</td><td>0</td></tr>
        <tr><td>stole</td><td>0</td></tr>
        <tr><td>stoll</td><td>0</td></tr>
        <tr><td>strohl</td><td>0</td></tr>
        <tr><td>strole</td><td>0</td></tr>
        <tr><td>stroll</td><td>0</td></tr>
        <tr><td>thoele</td><td>0</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried every **tablesorter** jquery plugin available in all websites, but some jquery library function(in my web page) is blocking the **tablesorter** from working...I don't know which one(though it's not given here)...I need to do the tablesort manually.

Is there any ideas, please advise me.....

Comment: what all have you tried ?

Comment: When i search **google** for the keyword 'tablesorter' ...whatever comes as result ...@masterofdestiny

Comment: Choose one of the Google results and add the code and error message to your question.

Comment: i mean can you make the tablesorter without jquery(is it possible i don't know, but it needs to be dynamic)

Comment: @Sven there is no error message, but the table doesn't have a sorting functionality

Comment: You need Js to manipulate the DOM.. So no (or you need to work with page refresh on sort). Just choose one jQuery plugin, add it to the page and look for the error. Copy paste it in your question and StackOverflow community will fix it for you and you learn something new..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi try this code it works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
<title>Light Javascript Table Sorter</title>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container table {
  width: 100%;
}

.container td, .container th {
  padding: 10px;
}

.container td:first-child, .container th:first-child {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.container td:last-child, .container th:last-child {
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.container th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container th.desc:after {
  border-top-color: #666;
}

.container th.asc:before {
  border-bottom-color: #666;
}

.container th:after, .container th:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.container th:after {
  border-top-color: #ddd;
  top: 22px;
}

.container th:before {
  border-bottom-color: #ddd;
  top: 10px;
}

.github {
  margin-top: 50px;
}



</style>

<script>

(function(document) {
    'use strict';

    var LightTableSorter = (function(Arr) {

        var _th, _cellIndex, _order = '';

        function _text(row) {
            return row.cells.item(_cellIndex).textContent.toLowerCase();
        }

        function _sort(a, b) {
            var va = _text(a), vb = _text(b), n = parseInt(va, 10);
            if (n) {
                va = n;
                vb = parseInt(vb, 10);
            }
            return va > vb ? 1 : va < vb ? -1 : 0;
        }

        function _toggle() {
            var c = _order !== 'asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc';
            _th.className = (_th.className.replace(_order, '') + ' ' + c).trim();
            _order = c;
        }

        function _reset() {
            _th.className = _th.className.replace('asc', '').replace('desc', '');
            _order = '';
        }

        function onClickEvent(e) {
            if (_th && _cellIndex !== e.target.cellIndex) {
                _reset();
            }
            _th = e.target;
            _cellIndex = _th.cellIndex;
            var tbody = _th.offsetParent.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0],
                rows = tbody.rows;
            if (rows) {
                rows = Arr.sort.call(Arr.slice.call(rows, 0), _sort);
                if (_order === 'asc') {
                    Arr.reverse.call(rows);
                }
                _toggle();
                tbody.innerHtml = '';
                Arr.forEach.call(rows, function(row) { tbody.appendChild(row); });
            }
        }

        return {
            init: function() {
                var ths = document.getElementsByTagName('th');
                Arr.forEach.call(ths, function(th) { th.onclick = onClickEvent; });
            }
        };
    })(Array.prototype);

    document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
        if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
            LightTableSorter.init();
        }
    });

})(document);
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
<section class="container">

    <h2>Light Javascript Table Sorter</h2>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>John Doe</td>
                <td>john.doe@gmail.com</td>
                <td>0123456789</td>
                <td>99</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jane Vanda</td>
                <td>jane@vanda.org</td>
                <td>9876543210</td>
                <td>349</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Alferd Penyworth</td>
                <td>alfred@batman.com</td>
                <td>6754328901</td>
                <td>199</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


</section>

    </body>
</html>
```

for live demo see this link....http://cssdeck.com/labs/light-javascript-table-sorter

Comment: Thanks Mate, But i tried this one...it's not working for me...Well i will post the script..which is giving me these difficulties...

Comment: his i have did some change see it

Answer (score 1):

Using the fantastic [tablesorter plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)  from Chrisrtian Bach it works fine with the code you have provided ([see here](http://jsfiddle.net/tXkb4/)).

**Script**

```
/*Make sure to include javascript and table sorter libraries*/    
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#newspaper-a").tablesorter({widgets: ['zebra']});
});
```

Try breaking down your problem. Set yourself up a test page with the bare minimum. I suggest the table and tablesorter scripts (and jquery). Then add your other javascritpt libraries one at a time until you can work out which one is causing the problem. If after adding the libraries you still can't replicate the problem you need to dig further into other scripts on your page and the mark up. Are there other elements with the same ID that you are attempting to bind the table to etc.